# Issue with capturing numeric values and displaying them - csh script

Tags: tcsh

I have abc1.log that has contents:

```
length: 2.3 %   
Internal breadth value (for calculation only): 63205 (including size \  
Internal area after transforming (for calculation only): 53000 (including type \  
Internal depth after cleaning and drying (for calculation only): 33221 (including area \
```

abc2.log that has contents:

```
length: 3.9 %   
Internal breadth value (for calculation only): 74605 (including size \  
Internal area after transforming (for calculation only): 23330 (including type \  
Internal depth after cleaning and drying (for calculation only): 99237 (including area \
```

I am using a csh script to extract the numerical values seen in each line after the symbol : in abc1.log and abc2.log, compare them and print a msg.

```
#! /bin/csh     
### case1   
set length_abc1=`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="length:") print $(i+1)}' abc1.log | bc`  
set length_abc2=`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="length:") print $(i+1)}' abc2.log | bc`  

if ($length_abc1:q > $length_abc2:q) then  
 echo $length_abc1  
 echo $length_abc2  
echo "ERROR: value of length_abc1 is greater than length_abc2"  
else   
 echo $length_abc1  
 echo $length_abc2  
echo "PASS: value of length_abc1 is smaller than length_abc2"  
endif
```

error encountered with the above case1 code is, If : badly formed number

```
### case2  
set breadth_area_depth_abc1=`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="only):") print $(i+1)}' abc1.log`  
set breadth_area_depth_abc2=`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="only):") print $(i+1)}' abc2.log`  

if ($breadth_area_depth_abc1:q > $ breadth_area_depth_abc2:q) then   
 echo $breadth_area_depth_abc1    
 echo $breadth_area_depth_abc2   
 echo "ERROR: value of breadth_area_depth_abc1 is bigger"  
else                                    
 echo $breadth_area_depth_abc1    
 echo $breadth_area_depth_abc2  
echo "PASS: value of breadth_area_depth_abc1 is smaller"   
endif
```

error encountered with the above case2 code is, If : Expression syntax

In case2, the variable breadth_area_depth_area1, variable breadth_area_depth_area2 will have values like  63205 53000 33221 and 74605 23330 99237 .

I would like to compare numeric values 63205 with 74605, 53000 with 23330, 33221 with 99237 and print the msgs. I am fine if that’s achieved either with one variable or three variables .
I even tried using below to capture 63205 numeric value (see in line 2 in abc1.log) in breadth_area_depth_abc1 but that also doesn’t work .

```
set breadth_area_depth_abc1=`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==" value (for calculation only):") print $(i+1)}' abc1.log`
```

Comment: may I pls know if anyone can help me in this regard.

Comment: I was able to find the solutions.Just in case if anyone requires this, For case #1,I used python $length_abc1 $length_abc2<<EOF if .. loop EOF  and solved it. For case #2, I used grep 'string' | cud -d\  -f9 to extract the numeric values for each line and used if loops later to compare